# Flutter's RawKeyboardListener on iOS

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use `RawKeyboardListener` on iOS, looking [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31945) leads me to believe this is something that is supported now. However, I don't see `onKey` getting called at all when any soft key press occurs on iOS.

What am I missing?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawKeyboardListener(
      focusNode: FocusNode(),
      onKey: (event) {
        print('Keyboard event detected');
      },
      child: const TextField(),
    );
  }
}
```